# golang Error: `cannot find package` when running go get

Tags: go

I'm trying to solve the example provided in Orielly book Decentrallized Applications.

The `go-ipfs` package seems to be outdated and the new version is not working fine. so I manually coping the older releases and try to compile go-kerala.

Eventhough some of the folder exists in the path I get error.

For example, 
`/home/rajkumar/go/src/github.com/ipfs/go-
     ipfs/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/jbenet/go-base58 (from $GOPATH)` is present after I have manually copied older release file but still go-get command gives error.

```
 $go get -d github.com/llSourcell/kerala
 package code.google.com/p/go.net/context: unrecognized import path 
 "code.google.com/p/go.net/context" (parse 
 https://code.google.com/p/go.net/context?go-get=1: no go-import meta 
 tags (meta tag github.com/golang/go did not match import path 
 code.google.com/p/go.net/context))
 package github.com/ipfs/go-
 ipfs/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/jbenet/go-base58: cannot find 
 package "github.com/ipfs/go-
 ipfs/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/jbenet/go-base58" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/ipfs/go-
 ipfs/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/jbenet/go-base58 (from $GOROOT)
    /home/rajkumar/go/src/github.com/ipfs/go-
 ipfs/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/jbenet/go-base58 (from $GOPATH)
 package github.com/ipfs/go-
 ipfs/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/jbenet/go-ctxgroup: cannot find 
 package "github.com/ipfs/go-
 ipfs/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/jbenet/go-ctxgroup" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/ipfs/go-
 ipfs/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/jbenet/go-ctxgroup (from $GOROOT)
 /home/rajkumar/go/src/github.com/ipfs/go-
   ipfs/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/jbenet/go-ctxgroup (from $GOPATH)
 package github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/jbenet/go-datastore: cannot find 
 package "github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/jbenet/go-datastore" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/jbenet/go-datastore (from $GOROOT)
    /home/rajkumar/go/src/github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/jbenet/go-datastore (from $GOPATH)
 package github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/jbenet/go-datastore/sync: cannot find package "github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/jbenet/go-datastore/sync" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/jbenet/go-datastore/sync (from $GOROOT)
    /home/rajkumar/go/src/github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/jbenet/go-datastore/sync (from $GOPATH)
```

Is there any step I'm missing to resolve the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've copied outdated code, which won't compile.

code.google.com/p/go.net/context

code.google.com has shut down, this is an old import path which can no longer be used. The error tells you what has gone wrong, that path can't be imported as it doesn't exist (try visiting it in a browser).

You could try to spend a lot of time fixing up the old imports, only to find that the packages have changed anyway and will no longer compile, so I'd recommend starting with the latest version and contacting the authors of github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs on github, or choosing another package to work with.

Comment: Maybe go should allow people to hold dependencies locally